# regex sets of 5 digits followed by a comma (trailing comma optional)

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got the following regex:

```
(\d{5}[,])
```

This matches the following:

```
12005,11111,11111,
```

but how do I make the trailing comma optional?

**EDIT:**

Acceptable results would be:

```
12005,

11111,11111,

12005

11111,11111
```

Unacceptable:

```
123456

123456,

12345,123456

123456,123456
```

Comment: `(\d{5}[,]?)` should do the trick.

Comment: Do you really want to make it just optional? It will always match the trailing comma even if you make it optional. Better tell us what you want the result to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\d{5}[,]?)
```

Will match

```
12005,11111,11111,
```

or

```
12005,11111,11111
```

Comment: This will also spuriously match `1234567890`.

Comment: it would also match `120051111111111`

Answer (score 5):

```
(\d{5})(?:,|$)
```

should do the trick.

To break this down,

- `\d{5}` - 5 digits
- `(?:...)` - just using parentheses to surround the `|`
- `,` - a literal comma
- `$` - end of input
- `,|$` - a comma or end of input.

The `|$` part is needed to avoid spuriously matching groups of digits not separated by commas like `"01234567889"`.

---

To see it in action, try

```
 JSON.stringify(
     ["01234", "01234,", "01234,56789", "01234,56789", "", "0123456789"]
     .filter(
         function (s) {
             return /^(?:(\d{5})(?:,|$))+$/.test(s);
         }))
```

which uses a larger RegExp to match one or more of these groups, so emits

> ```
> ["01234","01234,","01234,56789","01234,56789"]
> ```

Comment: This will also match the last 5 1s in `12005,1111111111`

Comment: @sachleen, Yeah.  You need to anchor at the front if you want to avoid suffix matches.  See the example code I added in my latest edit.

Comment: Here's a great tool that will explain your expressions automatically for you: http://regex101.com/r/xH2eA7

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this:

```
((?:\d{5},)*\d{5})
```

Will work if one set of 5 numbers or more than one separated by commas.  Or you could get fully explicit and slap the start and end on it:

```
^((?:\d{5},)*\d{5})$
```

Comment: The OP says "how do I make the trailing comma optional?" but this does not allow a trailing comma at the end at all.

Comment: @MikeSamuel, yup, you are right.  He did say that.  Guess I made the assumption he was looking to match a comma separated list of 5 digit numbers.  Your solution shows that, so I will leave mine alone.

Answer (score 1):

to make sure you don't match 5 digits from numbers with 6 or more digits, use a word boundary assertion (`\b`) and beginning of line assertion (`^`), like so:

```
(?:\b|^)(\d{5})(?:,|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

`\d{5}[,]*` - 0 or more or `\d{5}[,]?` - 0 or 1.